# Ember.js: Rendering template with parameters

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, emblem.js

I'm a novice in ember and I'm building a test app with ember.js. It's a calendar. I need to group events by day of week. In my controller I have something like this:

```
Calendar.WeekController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  sunday: ( ->
    @get('content').filterProperty('dayOfWeek', 0)
  ).property('content.@each.dayOfWeek')
  monday: ( ->
    @get('content').filterProperty('dayOfWeek', 1)
  ).property('content.@each.dayOfWeek')

# for all days of week
```

In my template:

```
ul
  each sunday
    li = description
```

I think that looks wrong, but I have no idea how to improve this. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you please provide me the complete current code? So I can see what I can do, use: http://jsfiddle.net/krisselden/uErrd/

Comment: why do you think it's wrong? please could you elaborate you question a bit more

Comment: @SunnyRGupta sorry, but your sample so complicated for me.

Comment: @intuitivepixel On next step i need view for month. Create property for every day of month - it's stupid. What if on next step i need view for year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your groups dynamically.

```
Calendar.WeekController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  groups: (->
    content = @get('content')
    for dayOfWeek in [0..6]
      Ember.Object.create
        dayOfWeek: dayOfWeek
        events: content.filterProperty('dayOfWeek', dayOfWeek)
  ).property('content.@each.dayOfWeek')
```

In your template:

```
each groups
  / TODO: Convert number to day name, for example, Sunday, Monday, etc.
  h1 = dayOfWeek
  ul
    each events
      li = description
```